# How to add padding to the map? here-map Android SDK

Tags: android, padding, here-api

In Google maps there is a method:

```
mMap.setPadding(padding.getLeft(), padding.getTop(), padding.getRight(), padding.getBottom());
```

How to set boundaries in HERE-Maps?

UPD: boundaries for camera. I want to draw a route on the map, then postpone the camera so that the route fits at the bottom of the screen. On Google maps, set the padding and align the map with respect to the new center (including padding). How to implement this in Here-Maps? sorry for my English

Comment: What kind of boundaries are you talking about.. Is it like restrict user to a city or country? or camera boundaries?

Comment: for camera boundaries

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko I stuck with the same problem. Did you find any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add padding to the view of google map then don't use setPadding method of google map sdk as it has different purpose refer this link for more details https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map

One way to give padding to google map view is by setting padding of its parent view like below

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here parent view of my google map fragment is frame layout so I gave it a padding of 8dp which will add view padding to the map

Answer (score -1):

The `setViewRect()` method may be what you are looking for.  From the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/MapOffScreenRenderer.html#setViewRect-com.here.android.mpa.common.ViewRect-):

> Set the view rectangle where the map will be drawn.

That said, if you aren't trying to change layout dynamically at runtime it is also a reasonable suggestion to set padding when defining your layout.  There is a [here-android-sdk-example](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/3f5f4e04f82c46d000a62dffe0299a32ef57046a/map-attribute/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml#L20-L29) you can take a look at which may not exactly be what you are looking for but may set your down that path as an option.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/settingsPanelLayout"
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/dim_foreground_disabled_material_light"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:visibility="gone">

...
</LinearLayout>
```

then you can `match_parent` with the `MapFragment` to pickup settings as [in this example](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/0d48bbed9b74eb536c777d60849b1d7baaa9be3d/map-objects/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml#L43-L47):

```
<fragment
    class="com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```